# Inconsistent docker resolv.conf behavior

Tags: docker, resolv.conf

I have 2 computer set up with Ubuntu 22.04.3 installed.

They both have the same docker version (25.0.3, build 4debf41).

However if I check the `resolv.conf` file in any container I create, the first one is copying the host `resolv.conf` whereas the other one has a file containing only the following line :

```
$ docker run -it --rm busybox
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.0.2.3
/ #
```

The expected one looks like :

```
$ docker run -it --rm busybox
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 169.x.x.x
search c.my-org-domain.internal routeraabbcc.com lan
/ #
```

It is nearly the same as my host machine.

I'm struggling to find the reason for this, because I need my container to re-use the host resolv.conf file which contains my organization dns.

Comment: Check `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Comment: I don't have any file like that

Comment: Then check if any options are passed to docker daemon on the command line.

Comment: There is a big difference when I look for docker processes. I followed this link https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/ to use docker in a rootless manner. But my computers have a different result.

The first one I set up last year does not show many processes:
`/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
/usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 27017 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 27017`

However in the install I did yesterday there is a `rootlesskit` programm running, and `rootlesskit-docker-proxy` also running

Comment: From what I understand, rootlesskit is starting with slirp4net, which is configured to use precisely this dns 10.0.2.3. I'm now trying to configure rootlesskit to use my host configuration instead